# como faço para pegar o link da página

Tags: javascript, html

Quero criar um botão de compartilhar para colocar em outros sites, como o do facebook, ou twitter e pra isso eu preciso que quando eu clicar no botão ele salve a url e mande para o meu email, como faço isso?

Comment: java != javascript (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/80920/1)

Comment: Use tags relevantes a duvida, **leia este link:** http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com isso você pode obter a url

```
var url = window.location.href.toString();
```

Aqui um exemplo simples para que quando o usuário clicar no botão, abra uma janela com a url. Possibilitando ser compartilhada (Ctrl + C)!

```
var copyBtn = document.getElementById('copyBtn');

copyBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    /*Pega url*/
    var url = window.location.href.toString();

    /*seta para que a mesma possa ser compartilhada*/
    window.prompt("Pressione: Ctrl+C, para compartilhar a url", url);

});
```

Html do botão

```
<button id="copyBtn">Salvar URL!</button>
```